# How can I change this color when I click the input or when I use TAB key moving over input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to change this blue color when I click this date input
Image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGKoH.png)

I tried with outline none on focus but didnt resolve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can u please provide a code sandbox link with ur code in it?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please be more specific when drafting your question. You stated that you want to change the blue color, but which ones specifically? The image you linked has multiple blue items: 1) the `29` in `29-Nov-2022`, 2) the `29` in the month view, and 3) the buttons `Clear` and `Today`. Also as others mentioned, posting a small code sample will really help us understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you are trying to modify is the color of the date fields when the focus is on them:

[image: input date example]

To do this "customization" you have to know mainly 2 things:

**Webkit**: Webkit is an html/css web browser rendering engine that works primarily in Safari and Chrome browsers.

**Focus**: It is a CSS pseudo-class, which refers to the element that is being focused on in the browser, usually activated when the user clicks, touches an element or selects it with the "Tab" key on the keyboard.

In the following example, I edit the appearance of **ALL** the inputs fields with the type **date** that have the **focus** on them and apply a red **background-color** to them, although you can also edit it using a class or the ID of your input.

```css
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:focus, 
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:focus,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:focus  {
    background-color: red;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="" id="">
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! If at all possible, if you could explain the code, as opposed to just leaving it, that'd be preferred. This appears to be a fringe case. Thank you!